# Can I return structure right from initialisation without creating temporary variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function which normally returns some `Point` structure:

```
/** Assume:
     private std::vector<Point> points_ **/
Point MyPoints::getLastPoint() const {
    //I need to return [0, 0] if there's no data
    if(points_.empty())
         return ???;
    else
         return points[points.size()-1];
}
```

The structure would be really simle:

```
struct Point {uint_32 x, uint_32 y}
```

I need to replace `???` with some structure initialization that can be returned. The only thing I could think was making `const` property:

```
const Point ZERO_POINT = {0,0};
```

Although this is probably what I'll do, I want to know if there's a way to initialize structure and immediately return it, such as when generating structure out of some existing variables.

Also you must assume that you cannot alter the original structure. And I'm asking with regards to `C++11` standard, and working with Visual Studio 2010 (which supports most of C++11 though).

Comment: So you want to return a `Point` without allocating memory for it? Even if you `return Point {0, 0};`, such temporary will still be copied/moved and have memory allocated for it.

Comment: No, I am not saving memory but lines of code. Also one-liner syntax is easier to read than the 4 line one.

Comment: @black I rolled back the edit, if you want to change tags accompany such doing with explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work if the compiler supports C++11 uniform initialization and does not require explicitly defined `Point` constructor:

```
return {0,0};
```

If uniform initialization is not supported, then define constructor on the `Point` structure and call it explicitly:

```
return Point(0, 0);
```

Comment: If neither worked for me, should I assume the compiler doesn't support this C++ feature?

Comment: @TomášZato: The first one should work for C++11 compiler with uniform initialization support. VS 2010 is not one of those. The second one does not require C++11, but you need to define constructor for the `Point` structure explicitly that takes those two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to save up lines, here's a one line

```
Point MyPoints::getLastPoint() const 
{
      return ( points_.empty() ? Point{0, 0} : points[points_.size() - 1] );
}
```